# Div will not stretch to 100% width when viewed on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, mobile

We have a search bar on our website that when viewed on an iPhone will not stretch across the page. If we do an Inspect on Chrome or IE and shrink the width of the screen or choose an iPhone emulator on Chrome, the search bar fills up the screen all the way across horizontally. But when we bring up the site on an iPhone, there is a white space gap on the right side of the screen. The website is www.skywalker.com. The html is old and cluttered. We have been working on cleaning up this code, so if you might see something that could be causing this behavior, please let me know.

The relevant html is where the element needing to stretch across has 
class="hideforhighres searchrow"

```
<div class="hideforhighres mobilesearch" style="text-align: center">
    <a id="ctl00_Header1_lnkStoreName2" class="logo hideforhighres" href="/" style="display:inline-block;height:72px;width:147px;"><img src="Images/Themes/skywalkerheader-sm.png" alt="Skywalker AV Supply" style="border-width:0px;"></a>
    <br>
<link href="/BVModules/Themes/Foundation4 Responsive/styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="ctl00_Header1_Search2_pnlSearchBox" class="row collapse search" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_Header1_Search2_btnSearch')">
    <!--Desktop-->
    <div class="hideforlowres" style="margin-left: 25px;">
        <input name="ctl00$Header1$Search2$KeywordField" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_Header1_Search2_KeywordField" placeholder="Search Products" style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-color:Black;height:32px;width:780px;">
        <div style="margin-top: -24px; margin-left: 778px;">
            <a id="ctl00_Header1_Search2_btnSearch" title="Search" class="searchbutton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$Header1$Search2$btnSearch", "", true, "", "", false, true))'> Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End of Desktop-->
<!--Mobile-->
<div id="PanelSearchMobile" class="row collapse search" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_Header1_Search2_btnSearchMobile')">
    &nbsp;<br>
    <div class="hideforhighres searchrow">
        <input name="ctl00$Header1$Search2$KeywordFieldMobile" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_Header1_Search2_KeywordFieldMobile" class="headersearchbox" placeholder="Search Products" style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-color:Black;">
        <a id="ctl00_Header1_Search2_btnSearchMobile" class="searchbutton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$Header1$Search2$btnSearchMobile", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Go</a>
    </div>
    <!--End of Mobile-->
</div>
</div>
```

In the css I have tried 100% and 100vw

```
/* Mobile Search width */
.mobilesearch .row.collapse.search .hideforhighres.searchrow {
    width: 100vw;
}

#PanelSearchMobile {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Does anyone know of problems where the iPhone browser acts differently than Android or desktop Chrome and IE?

Thank you

Comment: Does your head include a mobile viewport meta tag? Ex: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Ding, ding, ding, ding! Wow, it works! Thank you so much. I have been working on this for days. I was unaware of this meta tag for mobile.

Comment: @doppler Make the comment into a answer with a bit more explanation so the question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mobile browser may need additional information to scale the content properly. Try including the following `viewport` meta tag into your document's `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```